# location.href adds "" to file name

Tags: html, location-href

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<style>
    #wrap { 
        width: 1000px; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
    }
    .out_box {
        float: left;
        margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
        min-width: 280px;
    }
    input {
        margin: 10px;
    }
    input {
        vertical-align: -3px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 400%;
        color: black;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 100%;
        color: black;
        margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    }
    h3 {
        font-size: 95%;
        color: black;
        margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    }
    h4 {
        font-size: 200%;
        color: black;
        margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    }
    p, form, button {
        font-size: 80%;
        color: #252525;
    }
    .small_text {
        font-size: 70%;
        color: #737373;
    }
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=wrap>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form class="form1" action=”index3.htm”>
            <div class="formtitle">
                Enter the password to proceed
            </div>

            <div class="input nobottomborder">
                <div class="inputtext">
                    Password:
                </div>

                <div class="inputcontent">
                    <input type="password" id="password" /><br />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="buttons">
                <input class="orangebutton" type="submit" value="Login" onclick="if (document.getElementById('password').value == ’smurfsmurf’) location.href='index3.htm'; else alert('Wrong Password!');" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I make it redirect it does like this with the adress: `file:///Volumes/ETHERNET/"index3.htm"`.

There is a file in that directory named index.htm, and that's the file I am trying to access. How do I fix it adding the "" signs?

Best Regards

Oskar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong type of quotes in your form's action.  Change this line:

```
<form class="form1" action=”index3.htm”>
```

for this:

```
<form class="form1" action="index3.htm">
```

Also, because your javascript is on a button that will, according to standards, submit the form, your javascript will not react as you expect.  You should add a `return false;` into the code, and add your curly braces around your if statements, and remove the curved single quotes:

```
<input class="orangebutton" type="submit" value="Login" onclick="if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'smurfsmurf') {location.href='index3.htm';} else {alert('Wrong Password!');}return false;" />
```

Although, personally, I would recommend against inline JavaScripting like that.  Instead, use `EventTarget.addEventListener`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener  Scroll down to the example to see how it works.

**Explanation:**

Straight quotes are not *technically* necessary for HTML attribute values (I highly recommend using them anyway).  You have not used straight quotes (`"`), but instead curved quotes (`”`), which never were valid for wrapping HTML attribute vales.  Thus, the browser interprets your `action` on your form to be `”index3.htm”` instead of `index3.htm`.

When you click your `submit` button, the default action is to submit the form to it's `action` attribute.  So your browser is redirected to `/”index3.htm”`.  Your JavaScript won't have time to kick-in and change your browser's location before you are redirected to the form's action's value.

Let me know if that explanation makes since.

Comment: "Straight quotes are no longer technically necessary for HTML5 attribute values" — The rules for when quotes are needed around attribute values have changed little since the original HTML spec.

Comment: Thanks for all of your responses, it works!!!!!! How do I write the straight quotes on mac? And how do I center the button and text input?

Comment: Awesome!  Sorry - I don't have a mac.  Writing straight quotes will depend mostly on which keyboard (ex.: US English or Canadian French, etc.) you use.  Also, some non-plain-text editors may auto-convert straight quotes to curved quotes.  Are you trying to align vertically or horizontally?  for horizontal, use `text-align:center;` on the parent div.  You may want to create a `center` class and add it to the class list of those divs.